# ¿Cómo definir en TypeScript la clase de un array de objetos importados en JSON?

Tags: javascript, angular7, jsonarray

Tengo un *API Rest* que me pasa un array de objetos tipo:

```
[
   {
      "id":"2",
      "title":"Ping Pong Night Party",
      "description":"Una fiesta tematica, musica disco y mesas de pingpong...",
      "text":"texto aleator... jfhfifk",
      "images":"",
      "date":"2020-04-15 19:29:00",
      "place":"Valencia",
      "location":"C\/Sepulturero n\u00ba6.",
      "codigoPlus":"hg045f",
      "act":"1",
      "access":"public",
      "category":"party",
      "links":"http:\/\/www.findelmundo.com",
      "crew":"1,2,3,4,"

},
{...}
]
```

Estos se cargan en el atributo `selectedData`, que inicialmente está definido en *TypeScript* como:

```js
selectedData: any[];
//or
selectedData: classnameA[] | classnameB[];
```

El problema es que me gustaría especificar a qué clase modelo corresponden los objetos del array. El array se carga con datos de diversas *XMLHttpRequest*, según la petición que se ejecuta, el array hace referencia a una u otra clase.

Esta es la función que filtra qué petición *XMLHttpRequest* se hace.

```js
ejecuteService(service: string) {
    switch (service) {
    case 'Event':
        //
        this.servEvent.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
            this.selectedData = data;
        });
    break;
    case 'Content':
        //
        this.servContent.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
        this.selectedData = data;
        });
    break;
    case 'Crew':
        //
        this.servCrew.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
        this.selectedData = data;
        });
    break;
    default:
        //
        this.selectedData = [];
        console.log('el servicio solicitado no corresponde con ningun modelo');
        break;
    }
}
```

Necesitaría que el array de objetos...

```
selectedata [ Object{ },Object{ }Object{ } ]
```

... fuese un array del modelo correspondiente:

```
[ EventModel{ },EventModel{ } ] o [ CrewModel{ },CrewModel{ } ]
```

La solución sería que los objetos hagan referencia al modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir las interfaces de tus distintos modelos con las propiedades necesarias, y en el tipo `selectedata` puedes definir varios modelos. Por ejemplo:

```
interface EventModel { }
interface CrewModel { }

selectedData: Array<EventModel | CrewModel>;
```

Y en el servicio que se encarga de obtener los datos tu sabes que tipo de objeto devuelve, pues puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
ejecuteService(service: string) {

 switch (service) {
    case 'Event':
        // por ejemplo si esto devolvier un array de tipo EventModel[] en el parametro data puedes definir el tipo que esperas y asi con todos los casos.
        this.servEvent.getAll().subscribe ( data: EventModel[] => {
            this.selectedData = data;
        });
    break;
   // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: buenas, por lo que entiendo yo, el JSON tiene siempre la misma arquitectura por lo que con una única interfaz sería suficiente.

Comment: buenas, ahi como tu veas

Answer (score 0):

prueba creando una única interfaz y separando el tipo de respuesta en variables independientes.

```
interface Model {
   // Todos los campos que te devuelve el JSON
}

public eventModel: Model[] = [];
public crewModel: Model[] = [];
public contentModel: Model[] = []
```

De tal forma que en tu switch, puedas especificar en qué variable quieres guardar los datos.

```
ejecuteService(service: string) {
    switch (service) {
    case 'Event':
        //
        this.servEvent.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
            this.eventModel = data;
        });
    break;
    case 'Content':
        //
        this.servContent.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
        this.contentModel = data;
        });
    break;
    case 'Crew':
        //
        this.servCrew.getAll().subscribe ( data => {
        this.crewModel = data;
        });
    break;
    default:
        // Únicamente el mensaje de error
        console.log('el servicio solicitado no corresponde con ningun modelo');
        break;
    }
}
```